# Is there a way to define the size of a chunk in pandas as a function of available memory?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am aware that I can load a file containing data in chunks:

```
import pandas
for chunk in pandas.read_csv("path_to_my_csv.csv", chunksize=1e9):
    # Process
```

where the value of `chunksize` corresponds to the number of rows each "chunk" contains. What I want to be able to do is something like:

```
import pandas
for chunk in pandas.read_csv("path_to_my_csv.csv", chunkmem="200GB"):
    # Process
```

The reason I want to do this is to be able to process data on different machines (with different amounts of available RAM), and to parameterise my chunking in an automated way using `psutil.virtual_memory` or similar.

One way of doing this would be to calculate the memory footprint of a single row (from the datatypes of each column), and use that to parameterise the value of `chunksize`, but I'd ideally like to be able to do this with datasets of different structures.

Edit (In response to Bill Huang):

The way I would do this, given that there is no direct implementation in the Pandas API, is first to estimate the memory footprint of the data frame:

```
import pandas
numberOfRows = int(1e10)  # Known a-priori
firstRecord = pandas.read_csv("big_data.csv", chunksize=2).get_chunk()
firstTwoRecords = pandas.read_csv("big_data.csv", chunksize=3).get_chunk()
rowFootprint = (firstTwoRecords.memory_usage().sum() -
                firstRecord.memory_usage().sum())
estimatedFootprint = numberOfRows * rowFootprint
print(estimatedFootprint)
```

Then to divide available memory (from `psutil.virtual_memory`) by this estimate to get a chunk size. This estimator only requires reading the first two rows of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: No. There is just no such parameter as the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) shows.

**Useful answer**: You can **estimate** the suitable `chunksize`. For instance, guessing the average size of rows by reading the first 30 lines or so. But the odds of failure is really data-dependent.

```
import psutil
from pathlib import Path

# https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata?select=tmdb_5000_movies.csv
file_path = Path("/mnt/ramdisk/tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
fill_rate = 0.1
n_rows = 10

def estimate_bpl(file_path, n_rows=10):
    """Return estimates of bytes per line using the first n lines"""
    with open(file_path) as f:
        length = 0
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == n_rows:
                break
            length += len(line.encode('utf8'))
    return length / n_rows

avail_mem = psutil.virtual_memory().available
bpl = estimate_bpl(file_path, n_rows)
chunksize = int(avail_mem * fill_rate / bpl)

print(f"avail_mem={avail_mem}, fill rate={fill_rate}, bytes per line={bpl}, chunksize={chunksize}")
avail_mem=11166822400, fill rate=0.1, bytes per line=1409.4, chunksize=792310
```

Comment: Aye, shame. I think a better "hack" to compute the memory usage of the dataframe (if loaded in completely) would be to read a one-line chunk (using Pandas), extract the data types for each column (which are constant w.r.t. rows), sum their footprints, and multiply by the number of lines in the file. This removes your assumption in your estimate that the  UTF-8-encoded data of "N"-rows has the same footprint as the "N" records in the equivalent loaded dataframe, but consequently requires one to actually load in a chunk to test with.

Comment: If you were able to load the entire file into memory, then why read them by chunks and suffer from the extra overhead? So I think it is better to assume that you cannot always load the file into memory at once, and then take appropriate measures to this scenario accordingly.

Comment: My proposed solution doesn't involve reading the entire file - it only requires the first two rows to make an estimate of the footprint of the dataframe. I've edited my question to clarify what I mean.